# Why does this code produce a memory leak?

Tags: c++

Currently I have been banging my head against a school assignment and am dealing with some pretty nasty memory leaks. While debugging, I narrowed part of the issue down to a single piece of code.

Here is an extremely simplified version of that code that I tweaked to illustrate the leak:

```
   _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE ); 
   _CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT ); 
   _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE ); 
   _CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT ); 
   _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE ); 
   _CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT ); 

   do {
        char *name = new char;
        char *cname = new char[10];
        cin >> cname;

        name = cname;
        delete [] name;

    } while(false);

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
```

So my question is, why does this produce a memory leak? I've tried a bunch things to fix it, but nothing works.

EDIT:

Ah, seems that I have been misunderstanding how pointers operate. For some reason I was under the assumption that pointer initialized without a value points to **NULL** rather than a **block of memory**, and therefore doesn't need to be handled.

Simple questions get simple answers. Thank you.

Comment: `char* name = nullptr` would point to no memory, but calling `new` allocates memory (and thus needs to be deallocated)

Comment: You allocate a char, allocate 10 chars, do some stuff, delete the 10 chars, but never delete the single char (which you didn't actually need to allocate, but you did).

Answer (score 2):

You call new twice, but only delete once.

Comment: but worse, he overwrites one of his allocations, which can never be deleted afterwards, and the first allocation isn't even  needed

Answer (score 1):

you do `char* name = new char;`

but then later you replace (forget) the value of `name` with `name = cname;`

so that original `new char` is never deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you haven't tried deleting `name` - the first `char` you allocate before resetting `name` to something else and losing all references to the initial block...

Comment: +0.9 to offset downvote cause there's nothing wrong with this post

Comment: @Tas, was that a shady attempt to get round the prohibition on "+one" comments? If so, it probably should have been `+0.999...`. Or "+one" as another option, obviously :-)

Comment: <_< not at all! I'm hurt

Comment: Thanks for the "equalizer" - I just wanted to find out why someone downvoted a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the code to see what gets allocated and freed:

```
char *name = new char;       // Block 1, name references it
char *cname = new char[10];  // Block 2, cname references it
:
name = cname;                // name/cname now reference block 2 ***
delete [] name;              // free up block 2
```

You can see on the `***` line that you *lose* the pointer to block 1, hence there's your memory leak. Even if you *had* code which tried to free up block 1, you no longer have a reference to it after that point.

If you're going to lose all access to a memory block, you'd better free it up first:

```
char *name = new char;       // Block 1, name references it
char *cname = new char[10];  // Block 2, cname references it
:
delete name;                 // free up block 1
name = cname;                // name/cname now reference block 2 ***
delete [] name;              // free up block 2
```

---

As for your comment:

> For some reason I was under the assumption that pointer initialized without a value points to NULL rather than a block of memory, and therefore doesn't need to be handled.

What a pointer is initialised to if you don't specify, that depends on a couple of factors. However, it's irrelevant here because you *do* initialise it. If you want a pointer set to NULL, just do that:

```
char *name = 0;  // not "new char".
```